# How can I get data with getStaticProps in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getstaticprops

I have datas from getStaticProps. Bu I have problem when I get data inside function. I don't know how can I get.

```
export async function getStaticProps(){
    const res = await axios.get(`https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=10&skip=${page*10-10}`)
    const data = res.data
    console.log(data)

    return{
        props:{
            products: data
        }
    }
}
```

this is my getStaticProps. I need to this page from useState

```
export async function getStaticProps(){
    const res = await axios.get(`https://dummyjson.com/products?limit=10&skip=${page*10-10}`)
    const data = res.data
    console.log(data)

    return{
        props:{
            products: data
        }
    }
}

function Filter( { products } ) {

    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGbtc.png)

I don't know how can I get thi data

Comment: is the data not in the `products` prop passed to your Filter component?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your products in useEffect like below

```
useEffect(() => {
   setProducts(products);
}, []);
```

Because products have to be accessed in runtime not when build your project.
One the other things that i think can help you is when you use console.log in getstaticprops function your log is show when building project on IDE logcat and dont show on browser console.